# terminal in pycharm prints mess data

Tags: macos, terminal, pycharm

Using PyCharm CE 2017 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6.
when i'm trying to use terminal, after making some things and comfirming by 'enter' i have a lot of redundant data in output. For example:

```
133;C;1337;RemoteHost=apuzikov@77.88.0.89-1337;CurrentDir=/Users/apuzikov/Documents/projects/personal/python133;D;127133;A77:python apuzikov$ 133;Becho hi
hi
133;C;1337;RemoteHost=apuzikov@77.88.0.89-1337;CurrentDir=/Users/apuzikov/Documents/projects/personal/python133;D;127133;A77:python apuzikov$ 133;apuzikov$ 133;B
```

When I'm using itellij idea - everything fine. does anybody solved out how to remove this mess?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by following these step

Preferences --> plugins

Uncheck Python Terminal

Restart PyCharm